# How to iterate in blocks of n? I have two functions and want to run them alternately for blocks of 5

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two functions f1 and f2. I am iterating from 1-100, I want to run them alternatively like explained below.

For  i varying from 1-5 only f1 will run, and for i varying 6-10 only f2 will run, for 11-15 only f1 and for 16-20 only f2 and so on.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Next time at least try to do this on your own

Comment: And I just guess you meant i from 0-4 and from 5-9 as items for those will be 1-5 and 6-10.

Comment: Add the Code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone involved in this thread. Here's what I did after getting inspired from @DawidPi's and a friend's suggestion.

```
from math import ceil
for i in range(100):
    if (ceil(i%5))%2 == 0:
        f1
    else:
        f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(100):
    if i%(2*n) < n :
        fun1()
    else:
        fun2()
```

Comment: This is the solution for fixed blocks of 5, while running the job `n` times. I think the OP asked for the solution for fixed blocks of length `n`, while running the job 100 times. I think the OP asked for: `for i in range(100): if i % (2*n) < n: ....`

Comment: Hard to say, but above will do the job described above with saying "for i varying..."